# How to install and use jquery in ionic 2?

Tags: jquery, ionic2

How to install and use jquery in ionic 2? I use [ionic documentation for using third party libs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/) for it.

I have followed these steps:

1. npm install @types/jquery --save - it is OK
2. npm install @types/jquery-mask-plugin --save - it is OK
3. Add in **declarations.d.ts** file:

   declare module 'jquery';
   declare module 'jquery-mask-plugin';

But when I try to compile app, I got a Error:

```
Runtime Error
Cannot find module "jquery"
```

In tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I suggest giving some more info. for example how do you import jquery in your code?

Comment: also what tsconfig are you using?

Comment: I don't import jquery yet. Because the error is appears in declarations file where I write - declare module 'jquery';

Comment: I add information about tsconfig file.